# If $X$ is inductive then the set $\{ x \in X \mid x $ is transitive and $ x \notin x \}$ is inductive.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Definition.** We say that $A$ is an inductive set if $\varnothing\in A$, and whenever $x\in A$ then $x\cup\{x\}\in A$ as well.

I am trying to prove the following exercise:

> If $X$ is inductive then the set $U = \{ x \in X \mid x $ is transitive and $ x \notin x \}$ is inductive.

**Proof:** Let $\alpha \in U$, we have to show that $\alpha \cup \{ \alpha \} \in U$. But $\alpha \cup \{ \alpha \}$ is transitive since $(\beta \in \alpha \Rightarrow \beta \subseteq \alpha)$ and $(\alpha \subseteq \alpha \cup \{ \alpha \})$. Left to show: $\alpha \cup \{ \alpha \} \notin \alpha \cup \{ \alpha \}$. Suppose in contradiction that $\alpha \cup \{ \alpha \} \in \alpha \cup \{ \alpha \}$. This would imply $\alpha \cup \{ \alpha \} \in \alpha$ which implies $\alpha \in \alpha$ ($\alpha$ transitive). contradiction.

Is my proof correct?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as the definition of [transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_set) and the notion that $x\notin x$ are fairly simplistic, your proof might be correct.

I can think of two problems:

- $\alpha\subseteq\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$ does not imply $\alpha\in\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$ so your logic here is flawed.
- In the second part, your logical deductions of the implications are without foundations.

There is more on [inductive sets](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InductiveSet.html) and the [ZF axiom of infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_infinity) here.

An interesting case is where the base elements of a set are $a$ and $\{a\}$, at level $1$ we have induced elements $a\cup\{a\}$ and $\{a\}\cup\{\{a\}\}$, making the conjecture more difficult.

My attempt at a proof is:

Given $\alpha\in U$, we need to show:

1. $\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$ is transitive
2. $\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}\notin \alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$

1) If $\beta\in\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$, then we have one of $\beta\in\alpha$ and/or $\beta\in\{\alpha\}$ and $\beta\in\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}, \beta\notin\alpha, \beta\notin\{\alpha\}$. All $3$ imply $\beta\subseteq\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$, hence $\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$ is transitive.

2) Note that $\alpha\in\{\alpha\}$ therefore $\{\alpha\}\notin\alpha$, otherwise we would have $\alpha=\{\alpha\}$ which is absurd.

If $\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}\in\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$ then we have $\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}\in\{\alpha\}$ because we already know $\alpha\notin\alpha$ (from $\alpha\in U$), and therefore $\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}\notin\alpha$.

But we also have $\{\alpha\}\in\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$, and so using the same idea as before, $\{\alpha\}=\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$, which again is absurd. Therefore $\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}\notin\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$.

Therefore $U$ is inductive.

Comment: Actually, *everything* implies that $\alpha\in X\cup\{\alpha\}$, regardless to the contents of $X$.